# How to hide theme and plugin directory from page source using htacces?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using WordPress in my site. Theme name and some plugins name are showing in page source. I don't want to allow visitor to access the information for security reasons.

[image: sreenshot]

I want to hide the **/wp-content/themes/** and **/wp-content/plugins/** folders from page source with htaccess. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use W3 Total Cache plugin. it will combine all css and js file and also it will give a new name to file. So we can't see actual directory of theme and plugin. But this will work only for CSS and JS files. We will see link: http://www.example.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/M9QvyC8u0S3LTC0v1k3OL80rSS3STy4u1k8rygey81IA.css

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way ton achieve this, is through the use of a Plugin.

You should be able to achieve this, via the [WP Hide Security Enhancer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-security-enhancer/) Plugin.

Don't forget, themes and plugins often use their name, within CSS Classes.  Since CSS Classes are revealed within the Source Code, these could act as 'clues' as to the resources you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have standard [wordpress .htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) add the following lines after declaring `index\.php` rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# hide paths to wordpress dirs
RewriteRule ^theme/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/<yourtheme>/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^upload/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^plugin/(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/$1 [L]
# etc.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

now your files like

```
http(s)://your.site/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/css/style.css
```

become

```
/theme/css/style.css
```

If you want to achieve this replacement **automatically** (e.g. for plugins) add more constants to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL',   '/plugin' );
```

(See [WP_PLUGIN_URL](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/60bf5fefff3420553690c4b501c6ea3c435f045d/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L170) and other constants)

**PS**. I do care about "hidden" directories too, so I overwrite them later with

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/mytheme/$ /the/page/not-found [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/$ /the/page/not-found [L]
```

so they act like any other "Not Found" page.