# Hide theme name in url with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried several commands in .htaccess but none of them work for me, what I want is to hide the theme in the following way:

`https://example.com/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/js/example.js`

to

`https://example.com/wp-content/themes/js/example.js`

I am desperate because I cannot find the solution that works, I have tried the following codes that I have seen on stackoverflow:

1. [Hide directory name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url) The first answer
2. [How to hide theme and plugin directory from page source using htacces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214831/how-to-hide-theme-and-plugin-directory-from-page-source-using-htacces) The first answer
3. [WordPress URL/folder rewrite in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557991/wordpress-url-folder-rewrite-in-htaccess) The first answer
4. More...

They are all similar, but none work and some answers cause the css and js not to load.

Examples of code that I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^theme/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/<yourtheme>/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the plugin code, This when I use it I don't see any errors either and it only works with the plugin activated:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?vews/e2946d6c7d/(.*) /wp-content/themes/<yourtheme>/$2 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/wp-content/themes/<yourtheme>/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

I do everything from the .htaccess of the root directory.

I have tried to put it above the wordpress .htacces, below and within the wordpress .htacces, I have also downloaded a plugin that did it and I have copied the commands that it puts in the .htaccess, but when copying and pasting the code it does not work for me either Besides that I don't need so much hiding that the plugin does, I don't know what else to do because it doesn't work. Does anyone know what is wrong? Is there a better method?

Comment: "it does not work" does not really help. The question is: what happens? Please post your own implementation, your best attempt and state what exactly happens with that setup. What happens for a test request, do is not have any effect? Do you get an error? Do you get an unexpected result, which? What do your http server's error log files contain? And does your browser networking tab in the console show anything unexpected?

Comment: In the questions that I have put, for example the second, nothing happens, nothing changes, or gives an error: RewriteRule ^theme/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/<yourtheme>/$1 [L] ----- I put all the code as it puts it, modifying the name of the <yourtheme>.

Comment: What you are missing is that there are two distinct parts to this. Part one, is to rewrite incoming requests of the URL format you want, to the actual URLs that map onto the existing file system structure. This is the part handled by mod_rewrite. [...]

Comment: [...] The other part is, of course, to make WordPress output all references to anything theme-related, in your desired URL format in the first place. As long as the HTML that WP creates still refers to `/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/js/example.js`, there simply _is_ nothing for mod_rewrite to rewrite. So you will have to also look into WP's hook/filter mechanism, to modify the URLs it creates to anything theme-related.

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much for your explanation, I see that I would have to look for another script for the html, I think then I will leave it as it is.